# NetworkManager is not updating my /etc/resolv.conf according to the configuration I gave it

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, dns

I am setting up a VPN client on my laptop.

In order to avoid DNS leaks, I need to use the DNS servers provided by my VPN provider.
Let's say those servers are `<DNS1>` and `<DNS2>`.

In order to use those DNS servers, I issued the following commands:

```
nmcli con down <SSID>
sudo ifconfig <INTERFACE> down
sudo ifconfig <INTERFACE> up
nmcli con modify <SSID> ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
nmcli con modify <SSID> ipv4.dns "<DNS1> <DNS2>"
nmcli con up <SSID>
```

After that I reboot.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` is then as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Although NetworManager received the instructions:

```
$ nmcli con show <SSID> | grep dns
ipv4.dns:                               <DNS1>,<DNS2>
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   yes
```

Since name resolution doesn't work, I think it is still using the DNS servers provided by my ISP through DHCP.

If I force the DNS servers, the name resolution starts to work:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chmod 666 /etc/resolv.conf
sudo echo "nameserver <DNS1>" > /etc/resolv.conf
sudo echo "nameserver <DNS2>" >> /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chmod 444 /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Why is NetworkManager not updating the `/etc/resolv.conf` according to the configuration I gave it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have systemd-resolved enabled, so instead of the nameservers being configured directly in resolv.conf, they are configured indirectly via the resolved daemon.

Your resolv.conf points at the local 'resolved' service, and NetworkManager submits all nameserver information to that service via D-Bus, which you can then see using `resolvectl`.

- Related blog post: [Understanding systemd-resolved, Split DNS, and VPN Configuration](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2020/12/17/understanding-systemd-resolved-split-dns-and-vpn-configuration/)

If you want to disable this, change the `dns=` and `resolv-manager=` options in NetworkManager.conf.

(This is done because systemd-resolved allows for different connections to simultaneously have different DNS servers configured. For example, many people using a corporate VPN connection need to use the VPN-provided DNS for "corp.example.com" but would rather avoid using it for everything else because they do not want to leak their browsing history to the corp network.

Such configurations are impossible to express through resolv.conf alone, so one would need to use an intermediate such as Dnsmasq, Unbound, or – like in your case – systemd-resolved.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was accepted. Although I don't know why it was not using the correct DNS servers even through systemd-resolved.

Comment: @user1686 What values are needed for dns= and resolv-manager= in NetworkManager.conf ?

Comment: resolv-manager= does not exist in NetworkManager.conf. But rc-manager does. See 'man NetworkManager.conf'.